# Compiled program stops responding on other windows pc's

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

I have written a program in vc++14 that runs perfectly on my pc, both as a standalone executable, and debugging in visual studio 2015.

However, when I attempt to run it on a different pc, it stops responding immedietly. Using debug symbols, I have found any instantiation of classes via `make_unique`, or `make_shared` fails, causing null pointer exceptions.

I have checked and made sure that the target machine has the necessary vc++ runtime environments, and included any other dlls I can think of.

I have also tried statically linking the necessary libraries during builds, with no improvement.

I have even tried an installer project, which detected no additional dependancies.

I'm now at a loss. Is there anything else I should be looking for?

Comment: Can you run the remote-debugger on their machines? What are you passing into `make_unique`, exactly?

Comment: Verify the target platform is the same as yours. E.g., 64-bit vs. 32-bit

Comment: @Dai no arguments are being passed in. It's a basic instantiation, such as `m_States[0] = std::make_unique<ApplicationState>();`

Or, at least that's what the debugger indicates. Could you elaborate on remote debugging?

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername The project is targetting an x86 system, and runs on my x64 pc.

Comment: @IanYoung x86 usually means 32-bit target in VS.

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername Yes that's what I understood it to be. As far as I'm aware, targeting a 32 bit environment should be fine. As I said, My own machine is 64 bit and runs the executable just fine. In fact, the reference machine is almost the same, except that It does not have the visual c++ components installed in visual studio, but it does have the visual C++ 2015 runtime environment installed.

Answer (score 0):

Verify following.

1. Ensure you’re building a release build. It’s relatively hard to make debug builds run on a PC that has no visual studio installed.
2. Ensure you have the exact version of vc++14 runtime, including the service pack number. If you’re using vs2015 update 3, download and install this on the target PC: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53587 (the correct platform, 32 or 64).
3. Ensure you don’t have anything funny in your preprocessor: that you don’t have _DEBUG, no _SECURE_SCL, etc.

P.S. A dynamic link to C runtime is not necessary a good idea for a release build. One problem, on some Windows versions, you can’t update CRT to the version you need even using an offline installer, because recent CRT depends on some Windows Updates.

Comment: I'm definitely building in release mode.
I'll need to investigate the service pack number stuff, but assuming that is the case, is there a way that I can ensure that a target system has this installed and if not, rectify it?
I'm pretty sure I have NO_SECURE_CRT in the preprocessor. Could this be causing an issue??

Comment: Sorry the preprocessor has CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. Aside from that is all standard

Comment: I've removed and refactored my code so that the CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS preprocessor directive is no longer needed. No change there, but I found that the reference machine is a little behind with the cv++ 2015 redistributables, so we're installing that to see if it helps.

Comment: Well, we tested with the latest c++ redistributable on the target machine with no luck.